# PHP - Calling class functions from outside the class returns undefined function error

Tags: php

So I have a class and I created an object of the class outside of it. When I try to execute the function createSummonerBasicArray() I get this error `"Fatal error: Call to undefined function prepSummonerBasic()"`. So apparently it is saying `prepSummonerBasic()` does not exist. I tried making both functions public and it didn't change the error. New to PHP btw.

```
Class SummonerSearch{

    function prepSummonerBasic($summoner, $server) {

    }

    function createSummonerBasicArray($summoner, $server){
        $summonerBasic = prepSummonerBasic($summoner, $server);
    }

};

$obj = new SummonerSearch('crippy', 'na');
$obj->createSummonerBasicArray('crippy','na');
```

Comment: Have you tried `$this->prepSummonerBasic(...)` ?

Comment: I didn't but that was the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
function createSummonerBasicArray($summoner, $server){
    $summonerBasic = $this->prepSummonerBasic($summoner, $server);
}
```

you must call it with `$this->`, not like in java

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! That worked but can you explain a little about why $this-> is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with used `static` keyword:

```
<?php
Class SummonerSearch{
    public static function prepSummonerBasic($summoner, $server) {
        echo $summoner;
    }

    function createSummonerBasicArray($summoner, $server){
        $summonerBasic = self::prepSummonerBasic($summoner, $server);
    }
};

$obj = new SummonerSearch('crippy', 'na');
$obj->createSummonerBasicArray('crippy','na');
?>
```